# Error occured during the initialization of VM/ Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, heap-memory, minecraft, bukkit

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o false
PAUSE
```

I am trying to start run a craftbukkit server withe the code above and is giving me this error:

```
Error occured during the initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap.
```

I have a 64-bit with 16GB RAM (15.9GB USABLE)

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving the JVM enough heap. Try:

```
java -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o false
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are using a 32-bit JVM, and you couldn't reserve enough continuous space.  I suggest you make sure you are using a 64-bit JVM.